# How do I change my opinion on an edit?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I accidentally approved [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12018317). Is there any way of unapproving it?

Comment: No, there isn't. Note that the edit was later accepted by the OP themselves.

Comment: You could wait till it gets approved and fix the post yourself.